# Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-image-transport

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to get this to work for multiple weeks now. Very frustrated.

I have a pi 3 running Jessie. Ran all the steps in http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

and I am still getting "Unable to locate package ...." I cannot locate any of them.

My /etc/apt/source.list is
deb http://mirrordirector.raspian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

and my /etc/apt/source.list.d/ros-lastest.list is
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jessie main

My ultimate goal is to utilize [this](https://github.com/fpasteau/raspicam_node) code to publish images/videos from the pi over ros node back to my laptop computer.

Can somebody help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258755/unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-image-transport/) by [stallionAJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29956/stallionaj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex Beh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33685/alex-beh/) on 2018-04-01**:
May I know how you solve it? I struggle for it for a long time but still don't know how to solve it

I donlt know how to install ros package from source on raspberry pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've installed ROS from source, so you should follow the directions at the end of the installation about [adding released packages](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi#Adding_Released_Packages) when you want to install additional packages.

Since you've installed from source, you shouldn't expect to install new packages through apt-get.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1